# Sabre Air Availability Soap Api v-2.4 Throws an Exception ERR.SWS.CLIENT.INVALID_SERVICE

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, soap-client, sabre

I am creating soap request for air availability sabre api. i am using soap parameters from api documentation. first i request to get session token, and i am getting one successfully, but when i firing api request i am getting service error. it saying that i am using Invalid service or version and its 500 error. i have checked everything not sure what to do next. please help.

sabre api link: https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/air/search/Air_Availability
here is the request snippet of postman:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <eb:MessageHeader SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" eb:version="2.0">
            <eb:ConversationId>rajdeepa555@gmail.com</eb:ConversationId>
            <eb:From>
                <eb:PartyId type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">WebServiceClient</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:From>
            <eb:To>
                <eb:PartyId type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">WebServiceSupplier</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:To>
            <eb:CPAId>F9CE</eb:CPAId>
            <eb:Service eb:type="sabreXML">OTA_AirAvailLLSRQ</eb:Service>
            <eb:Action>OTA_AirAvailLLSRQ</eb:Action>
            <eb:MessageData>
                <eb:MessageId>mid:20031209-133003-2334@clientURL</eb:MessageId>
                <eb:Timestamp>2017-06-20T11:15:14Z</eb:Timestamp>
                <eb:Timeout>50</eb:Timeout>
            </eb:MessageData>
        </eb:MessageHeader>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/ACPCRTD!ICESMSLB\/CRT.LB!-3261887980644185979!896467!0
            </wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
         </wsse:Security>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <eb:Manifest SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" eb:version="2.0">
            <eb:Reference xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="cid:OTA_AirAvailRQ" xlink:type="simple"/>
        </eb:Manifest>
        <POS>
            <Source PseudoCityCode="F9CE"/>
        </POS>
        <OTA_AirAvailRQ Version="2.4.0" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <OriginDestinationInformation>
                <FlightSegment DepartureDateTime="12-21">
                    <DestinationLocation LocationCode="LHR" />
                    <OriginLocation LocationCode="DFW" />
                </FlightSegment>
            </OriginDestinationInformation>
        </OTA_AirAvailRQ>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the Body only includes the OTA_AirAvailLLSRQ payload and you'll get a successful response.

```
 <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <OTA_AirAvailRQ Version="2.4.0" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <OriginDestinationInformation>
            <FlightSegment DepartureDateTime="12-21">
                <DestinationLocation LocationCode="LHR" />
                <OriginLocation LocationCode="DFW" />
            </FlightSegment>
        </OriginDestinationInformation>
    </OTA_AirAvailRQ>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

Comment: Yes i tried that earlier but getting this error then    
      <stl:ApplicationResults status="Unknown">
                <stl:Error type="Application" timeStamp="2017-06-24T02:55:02-05:00">
                    <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
                        <stl:Message>Sending request to the Host failed</stl:Message>
                        <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.CONNECTOR_ERROR</stl:ShortText>
                    </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
                </stl:Error>
            </stl:ApplicationResults>

Comment: This RQ worked fine for me. Are you still getting the same error returned? Or was it just once?

Comment: Hi Bruno Thanks for reply. i tried the request accordingly, but still getting another error "Sending request to the Host failed" so i am confused how to fix this. i think i need to know some of the placeholders value. so can you please tell me how to get value of some fields like CPAId, Service, partyid and finally PseudoCityCode. i don't know where to get them from. also can you please tell me correct end point for this request. thanks

Comment: The placeholders are not the issue since I got a successful response with the same one with the modification that I mentioned. 
The endpoints are documented on this page: 
https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_basics/environments
Useful info:
https://developer.sabre.com/resources/getting_started_with_sabre_apis/

Comment: Thanks Bruno for your quick reply, can you please share your code. postman file or your code base. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Tied to Brunos comments, the below requested worked fine:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="0">
            <eb:From>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">from</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:From>
            <eb:To>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">ws</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:To>
            <eb:CPAId>YOURPCC</eb:CPAId>
            <eb:ConversationId>YourConversationId</eb:ConversationId>
            <eb:Service eb:type="sabreXML"></eb:Service>
            <eb:Action>OTA_AirAvailLLSRQ</eb:Action>
        </eb:MessageHeader>
        <eb:Security xmlns:eb="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="0">
            <eb:BinarySecurityToken>YOUR SESSION TOKEN</eb:BinarySecurityToken>
        </eb:Security>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
<OTA_AirAvailRQ Version="2.4.0" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <OriginDestinationInformation>
        <FlightSegment DepartureDateTime="12-21">
            <DestinationLocation LocationCode="LHR" />
            <OriginLocation LocationCode="DFW" />
        </FlightSegment>
    </OriginDestinationInformation>
</OTA_AirAvailRQ>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```